# Flow text alignment issue

Tags: ruby, shoes

When I run my code it crashes with the error: undefined method para for nil:class. All I am trying to do is make the text appear to the right of the button that is declared. Anybody know how to fix this?

My code (using ruby version 2.0.0, latest green_shoes version):

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app do            
fl=flow(margin: 12) do
    openBtn=button "Btn Here"
    begin
        fl.para "text should appear to right of button"
        lc=edit_line()  #should be on its own line
    rescue Exception=>ex
        puts "error in application: \ntype: #{ex.class}\nmessage: #{ex.message}"
    end     
end 
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: thanks for the tip, I made my question more obvious.